# wordpress url resolution of subpages from within plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, url, plugins

Say I have a Page "foo" in wordpress such that http:/www.blah.com/foo brings it up.

Say this page has a trigger within its content such as <!-- foo --!> which is being tracked by my plugin through the add_filter('the_content', ..) filter. So, all calls to http:www.blah.com/foo and http://www.blah.com/foo?var=bar are picked up by the plugin and dealt with.

Now is there a way by which the plugin could let wordpress know that it wants to handle all urls of the type http://www.blah.com/foo/bar http://www.blah.com/foo/bar/morefoo etc..
"without" having to create pages/subpages for each of these as these urls would be created dynamically?

Also, is there anyway besides using the add_content filter on the_content within a page that one can grab control from within a plugin ideally keyed of the url so all calls to http://www.blah.com/foo are handled by the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own q:

The pointers in the answers above were useful and got me going on the right track, but I kept hitting a snag in that whenever the url in question was invoked it kept calling index.php.

I then came across http://mikeschinkel.com/blog/restful-web-services-in-wordpress-plugin/ 
where he goes into an explanation and provides an answer that requires a template_redirect action to ensure that control is where you want it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can grab URL references (aka queries) and parse them, without creating subpages.

The sequence of events is described in the [Query Overview page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview). You want to look at hooking into the `parse_request` action in particular.

Answer (score 1):

I do something very similar to what you describe using a custom mod_rewrite rule.  Following your example, I have a page Foo that uses the template foo.php.  The foo.php template accepts a query variable, say "path", that defines the remainder of the URL.  In my .htaccess file, I have the following rule (be careful to put it *outside* WordPress' automatically-generated rules!):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^foo/(.+) /foo/?path=$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Your plugin may also need to disable the "redirect_canonical" plugin, which can poach your URLs unexpectedly.

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

I think it may also be possible to do something similar using the [template_redirect](http://wphooks.flatearth.org/hooks/template_redirect/) hook and [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite) class, but I have not tried it myself.