# How can I create (custom) friendly URL in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, friendly-url, seo

In Wordpress, I have set the permalink structure like this: `/%category%/%postname%`

After creating a custom search page, I now have the following URL:
`http://mypage.com/search?foo1=bar&foo2=&foo3=&foo4=`

I have two questions:

1) How can I transform this url so that I get to e.g. `http://mypage.com/search/foo1/bar` ?

2) Is there a way I can remove the "unused" parameters? (`&foo2=&foo3=&foo4=`)

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694563/wordpress-plug-ins-how-to-add-custom-url-handles), pointing me to [parse_request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview) function in Wordpress, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498105/wordpress-url-resolution-of-subpages-from-within-plugin) talking about mod_rewrite. But not quite sure how to proceed, or what method is better to use.

Answer (score 0):

you can use both the methods `parse_request()` function of wordpress or `mod_rewrite` for transforming your url, but for that to work properly you will have to write a function that catches the requested url and translates it into original url to serve the request.